# Spacer not greedy when in a geometry reader that's inside Scrollview with safeAreaInset

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, geometryreader

This used to work, but seeing this problem with Xcode 15.0.1

This view works as expected:

```
#Preview {
    VStack {
        Text("Header")
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Top").background(Color.red)

                    Spacer().background(Color.orange)

                    Text("Bottom").background(Color.blue)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting in:
[Top and Bottom are in the right spot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYVUI.png)

But then adding either something below the Geometry Reader or a .safeAreaInset as so:

```
#Preview {
    VStack {
        Text("Header")
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Top").background(Color.red)

                    Spacer().background(Color.orange)

                    Text("Bottom").background(Color.blue)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height)
            }
        }
    }
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
        Text("Footer")
    }
}
```

Results in the Spacer() not taking up any space (Top and Bottom are then centred in the middle of the scrollview.
[Spacer not taking up any space, so Top and Bottom are in the centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTO7E.png)

As I mentioned at the top, this was working previously. Any clues to if this is a SwiftUI bug or something I'm doing wrong?